# Fit an SVG text inside an SVG background rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Here is a box containing two SVGs. one for the text and one for the background rectangle.

I want to fit the text inside the background rectangle. so that there is no text stretching out of the background rectangle. (Note that I don't want to line break the text I want to decrease the dimensions of the text or something to fit the text inside the rectangle in a single line);

I have tried a lot of solutions with no luck and I think maybe there are no pure CSS solutions, So even Javascript to fix this wired issue is accepted.

Note: I really need the text and the background rectangle to be SVGs.

[Here is the CodePen.](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/WNwGpMr?editors=1100)

And Here is the code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box, svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 2.59vw;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.59vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-13" class="box" style="width: 35.0663246486498vw;">
   <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 45">
      <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
         <tspan id="span-15">This is a long text that should be fit This is a long text that should be fit This is a long text that should be fit</tspan>
      </text>
   </svg>
   <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
         <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomIdA-4">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
         </linearGradient>
         <filter id="uniqueDomIdB-4" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
            <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
            <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
            </feGaussianBlur>
            <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
         </filter>
      </defs>
      <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomIdC-4" filter="url(#uniqueDomIdB-4)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>
      <g id="uniqueDomIdC-4">
         <g>
            <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" fill="url(#uniqueDomIdA-4)"></path>
         </g>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Changing veiwBox seems promising But I have no idea how to calculate it! I can calculate box width but I don't know how to find viewBox...?

Comment: No it doesn't work for me...

Comment: You can use `<tspan textLength="100%" ` but since your svg is stretched ` height="100%" width="100%"` you'll need to remove the viewBox to make it work (I wouldn't do it). The text will apear jammed together. Another solution would be using a proper viewBox without streatching the svg and recalculating the font size

Comment: How can I calculate a proper veiwBox using Javascript?

Comment: Changing veiwBox seems promising But I have no idea how to calculate it! I can calculate box width but I don't know how to find viewBox...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the box is very small and the text is very long the text will be bearly visible.

In javascript I'm getting the length of the text: `span15.getComputedTextLength()` and I'm using this value for the viewBox attribute

```js
let text_length = span15.getComputedTextLength();

document.querySelector("#first").setAttribute("viewBox",`0 0 ${text_length} 45`)
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
    outline:solid red;
}

body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 2.59vw;
  outline:solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-13" class="box" style="width: 35.0663246486498vw;">
   <svg id="first" viewBox="0 0 100 45">
      <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
         <tspan id="span15">This is a long text that should be fit This is a long text that should be fit This is a long text that should be fit</tspan>
      </text>
   </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: I sum an extra 70 to the text length to add some paddings to the text ... is that a proper solution or you may suggest a better one?

Comment: I would do the same. 70 would give you a "padding" of 35

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="box-13" class="box" style="width: 35.0663246486498vw;">
  <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
         <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomIdA-4">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
         </linearGradient>
         <filter id="uniqueDomIdB-4" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
            <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
            <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
            </feGaussianBlur>
            <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
         </filter>
      </defs>
      <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomIdC-4" filter="url(#uniqueDomIdB-4)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>
      <g id="uniqueDomIdC-4">
         <g>
            <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" fill="url(#uniqueDomIdA-4)"></path>
      <foreignObject
        x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
      >
          <p style="font-size: 1.8vw;line-height:1.2;text-align:center;">This is a long text that should be fit This is a long text that should be fit This is a long text that should be fit</p>
       
      </foreignObject>
         </g>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: (Note that I don't want to line break the text I want to decrease the dimensions of the text or something to fit the text inside the rectangle in a single line);